# Portable Python Script with Module

Tags: python, module, portability

I'm new to using python modules.

I'm currently working on a python 2.7 script that will be deployed to many remote computers (which have python 2.7 on them). The problem is that the script needs to use a module, which *I am **not** allowed to install* on those computers.

I'm wondering if it is possible to include the module files in the same package as my script (possibly have them compiled first), and then have the script import the library from that local folder, thus achieving a "portable" script.

If that is possible, how would I go about doing that?

---

Specifics: I'm running 2.7.11 on Windows needing to use Paramiko.

I'm asking this question because the similar questions that I can find either do not answer mine, or expect me to be familiar with core python structures with which I am not. I also DON'T want to include the entirety of python and then install the module onto that, something I see is often called Portable Python. I just want to send my script and the module and nothing more.

---

Many thanks!

Comment: to keep all modules in the same directory you can try something "pip install module --target=."

Comment: @JishnunandPk - I'm assuming that creates a compiled version of the module in the directory that I specify, correct? If so, then how to I import those modules in my code, because I fear that running it on a separate python implementation would cause the imports to break?

Comment: by default python search for those modules in same directory first then if not available it will search for python install lib files.

Comment: @JishnunandPk - I tried it and it works wonderfully! Could you post the info from both your comments as a short answer so that I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install modules in a specific directory, you can try  `pip install module --target=.`

By default python search for those modules in same directory as the script first, then, if not available, it will search for python install lib files.